# Moving a window between Spaces with Slate

Tags: macos, mac

I'm currently using Slate as my main TWM but the only thing missing is moving app between spaces with key bindings.

I don't want to use the mouse, I know I can drag and drop the window and I can select the window and then switch to an other Space.

I want to do it with the keyboard, just switch the window on focus. Is it possible? Is there a better TWM for mac os than Slate?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a spaces support in slate for now. For more info take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/jigish/slate/issues/78).
You can also use something like BetterTouchTool app for this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I found this, [since not sure what you asking](http://thume.ca/howto/2012/11/19/using-slate/)

> Switching Windows
>
> Slate allows me to switch to any window I want in one shortcut and a
>   single key press. I can do this using a feature called “Window Hints”.
>   If you have ever used easyMotion for Vim or Vimperator/Vimium you will
>   be familiar with this concept.
>
> When you press a shortcut (I use cmd+e), every window is instantly
>   overlain with a letter, starting with those on the home row of your
>   keyboard. By pressing the letter over a window your focus is
>   transfered to that window. For windows that are hidden behind others
>   the application icon is displayed in the overlay.

Comment: The question is about moving an application to another space, the link does not provide any related information.